# How to integrate Phonegap with Sencha Touch 2.4 and CMD 5.0?

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, phonegap-build

I'm trying to integrate Sencha Touch with Phonegap on the new version, I've tried different settings I found on the internet but always get the same screen and no error is displayed (now, because before I had many mistakes and solving).

Wanted help to successfully integrate everything and be able to use the build.phonegap.com in my Sencha Touch applications.[image: stop in this screen and not upload to build or run in my mobile]

Comment: Try running 'sencha -d app build native' to see a more detailed error log. I just wrote a tutorial on how to set this up as well: http://www.joshmorony.com/building-your-app-remotely-with-phonegap-build-and-sencha-cmd/

Answer (score 0):

What do you see in PhoneGap Build? Do you see that your app was uploaded?

You can try manual way:

Create a testing build:

```
sencha app build testing
```

Then zip 'build/testing' directory and send it to PhoneGap Build using Web interface.

If this will work you double check that your is correct: http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/cordova_phonegap.html

If something will go wrong post your app.json file